# ValueError EasyOCR

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, ocr

!python "C:\Users\saivi\Internship ML(OCR)\PaddleOCR\ppstructure\table\predict_table.py" --det_model_dir="C:\Users\saivi\Internship ML(OCR)\PaddleOCR\ppstructure\inference\ch_PP-OCRv3_det_infer.tar" --rec_model_dir="C:\Users\saivi\Internship ML(OCR)\PaddleOCR\ppstructure\en_ppocr_mobile_v2.0_table_rec_infer.tar" --table_model_dir="C:\Users\saivi\Internship ML(OCR)\PaddleOCR\PaddleOCR\ppstructure\en_ppocr_mobile_v2.0_table_structure_infer.tar" --image_dir="C:\Users\saivi\Internship ML(OCR)\PaddleOCR\ppstructure\docs\table\table.jpg" --rec_char_dict_path="C:\Users\saivi\Internship ML(OCR)\PaddleOCR\ppocr\utils\dict\table_dict.txt" --table_char_dict_path="C:\Users\saivi\Internship ML(OCR)\PaddleOCR\ppocr\utils\dict\table_structure_dict.txt" --det_limit_side_len=736 --det_limit_type=min --output "C:\Users\saivi\Internship ML(OCR)\PaddleOCR\PaddleOCR\ppstructure\output\table"

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\saivi\Internship ML(OCR)\PaddleOCR\ppstructure\table\predict_table.py", line 237, in 
new_var = new_func(main, args)
File "C:\Users\saivi\Internship ML(OCR)\PaddleOCR\ppstructure\table\predict_table.py", line 219, in new_func
main(args)
File "C:\Users\saivi\Internship ML(OCR)\PaddleOCR\ppstructure\table\predict_table.py", line 153, in main
table_sys = new_func1(args)
File "C:\Users\saivi\Internship ML(OCR)\PaddleOCR\ppstructure\table\predict_table.py", line 214, in new_func1
table_sys = TableSystem(args)
File "C:\Users\saivi\Internship ML(OCR)\PaddleOCR\ppstructure\table\predict_table.py", line 68, in **init**
args)) if text_detector is None else text_detector
File "C:\Users\saivi\Internship ML(OCR)\PaddleOCR\tools\infer\predict_det.py", line 142, in **init**
args, 'det', logger)
File "C:\Users\saivi\Internship ML(OCR)\PaddleOCR\tools\infer\utility.py", line 201, in create_predictor
model_dir))
ValueError: not find model.pdmodel or inference.pdmodel in C:\Users\saivi\Internship ML(OCR)\PaddleOCR\ppstructure\inference\ch_PP-OCRv3_det_infer.tar